# REGEX Email Validation To Not Allow Commas In Domains

Tags: regex, email-validation

I am using the following expression to validate emails:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|com|COM|CoM|cOM|coM|COm|edu|org|net|gov|biz|info|name|aero|biz|info|jobs|museum)\b
```

However, it still allows me to enter an invalid email such as below...

```
mynameis@domain.co,uk
```

I want to not allow the comma between the co and uk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Regex can be quite different across different languages. Which language you're using?

Comment: You don't seem to allow commas anywhere, is that what you are after?

Comment: Did you search SO for email validation regex? This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: maybe you need to escape some special characters (like +) to improve your regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses

Comment: sometimes the best way is to split e-mail by `'@'` and check first and second parts of splitted string.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want commas anywhere, you could try to lookahead.
  `^(.(?!,))*$`
With this, if you have a comma anywhere, it will no longer match.  Of course you'll need to place this in your existing expression, without the start and end anchors.  I recommend [Regexpal](http://Regexpal.com) to test such regular expressions.

Additionally, you may wish to exclude double periods from your email address.  I use:

`^(?!.*\.{2})[ ]*[\w]+[\w\.]*[\w]*@[\w]+\.[a-zA-Z]+[ ]*` for my needs.

Now `\w` allows for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` which is odd due to the underscore but I'm pretty sure underscores *are* allowed in email addresses.  This also prevents a double period in your email address as well as not allowing the first or last character to be a period, which is illegal.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to allow commas anywhere as this is only for a single email address, so no need to add a comma separator for multiple email addresses.

Comment: This one seems to work...   ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$

Comment: That might work, however be careful as you cannot have two consecutive periods in a row with your email address.  I'll update my answer with a solution for that.